# Fast extraction of frames from webcam: C++ & OpenCV vs. Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, webcam

I've been developing a real-time image analysis project using C++ and OpenCV that requires frames to be extracted from a webcam. I'm running into problems trying to extract these frames at any kind of speed - currently I can only manage approximately 18 fps. Here is the simple code I'm using to extract frames from webcam:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) return -1;
    namedWindow("video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    clock_t start = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 101; ++i)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        imshow("video", frame);
        waitKey(1);
    }

    clock_t finish = clock();

    double time_elapsed = (finish - start) / 1000.0;
    double fps = 100 / time_elapsed;

    cout << "\n\nTIME: " << time_elapsed << "\n\nFPS: " << fps << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried other codes but none allow me to extract the frames faster than 18 fps. I'm hoping to reach speeds similar to what I can achieve in Matlab of 40 - 50 fps (using the following code):

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'MJPG_640x480');
triggerconfig(vid, 'manual');    
start(vid);

tic;

for k = 1:100;
    clc;
    disp(k);
    I = peekdata(vid, 1);
    imshow(I);
    drawnow;
end

toc;

close();
stop(vid);
delete(vid);
```

I've looked at using mex files to speed up my C++ project and also enabling GPU / CUDA support but I've hit some hardware problems so I was seeing if there is a simpler approach or something I'm missing in my current code.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** I just ran a performance analysis on the code and there's a few sticky points namely:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);            10.5%
cap >> frame;                   36.8%
imshow("video", frame);         31.6%
```

Comment: could you test the code at http://answers.opencv.org/question/72386/how-to-get-fps-in-opencv-live-capture/ let me know if there will be any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Trying out both examples in your link only allowed me to reach an average of 15fps.

Comment: if you run debug mode, try release mode.

Comment: I just tried both versions of the code in the link in release mode and only got a maximum of 18 fps.

Answer (score 3):

waitkey(1) is slowing you down. You can try to do it on each, for example, tenth iteration. See http://answers.opencv.org/question/52774/waitkey1-timing-issues-causing-frame-rate-slow-down-fix/

Your way of calculating FPS is rather bad. Try
`double time_elapsed = (finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`
It is not guaranteed that CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000

Comment: `waitKey(1)` should only slow down 1ms, it could be that the webcam is slow in producing frames. That is not uncommon with cheap webcams

Comment: Actually, it dispatches all messages a window recieves, so it takes *at least* 1ms.

Comment: Right, but still with 18 FPS you have 55ms to process each frame. At 30 FPS you would still have 33ms, so if its 1 or 5ms for `waitKey(1)` does not matter I think. You still end up waiting for the webcam.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had a read through the link and implemented their technique of only calling the lines `imshow("video", frame)` and `waitkey(1)` every tenth iteration but I'm still only achieving the same speeds. I've also changed that iteration to be larger with no luck. With another performance analysis on this new code it seems it is being held up by the `cap >> frame` line.